# Using both PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and PropertySource

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I am having a bit of a difficulty here. I am designing a utility for which I require the ability for my Spring context to treat command-line arguments as properties. This was easily done:

```
if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
    PropertySource<?> ps = new SimpleCommandLinePropertySource(args);
    ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(ps);
}
```

What I have a problem with is the next step: to be compliant with my enterprise framework, I must set a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` they provide<sup>1</sup>. Easily done too.

```
@Bean
public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

The thing is, once the latter is set, what was previously working with the command-line is not, and I have errors:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'input.file' in string value "${input.file}"

Now, I am aware using both is far from ideal (and that ideally, I should not even be using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` but rather `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`). Yet, I have no choice as to the configurer.

As a consequence, I think I must change something with my `PropertySource`, but I am at a loss as to how I can do it in an elegant way. Should I extend the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to add the `PropertySource`? Is that even possible?

What is the best solution to go for in this case? Even vague leads are welcome, since I don't know in which way to go.

(Spring version: 4.1.6)

---

<sub>1. This `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` loads some properties files and apply some additional processing (e.g. to allow encrypted values in the properties files).</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the

```
 ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(ps);
```

you go right way.

I think your `MyPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` (from that Enterprise Framework) isn't just compatible with the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

You should take a look to their code and override it to extend `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

From other side `PlaceholderConfigurerSupport` is a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and these guys must be configured as a **static** `@Bean`s.

HTH

Comment: The addFirst seems to be ignored because of the configurer. I hoped to avoid rewriting framework code, but I think that's the only way. Meeting some problems (it appears they sold me dream) but your answer meets my thoughts.